# Tapping on a Custom Annotation and Do Functions Accordingly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotationview

I try to implement tapping on a custom annotation, when it is tapped, the row of this on table will be highlighted,

I tried adding gesture recognizer to custom annotation, but it does not work.

I alsa tried annotation did select method, the result is the same.

My code is as below;

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *singlePress =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSinglePress:withIndex:temp:)];

    [annotationView addGestureRecognizer:singlePress];

    [annotationView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add callout button on annotationView  such like,

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myCustomAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

and call method

```
-(void)showDetails:(UIButton *) calOutBtn
{
   // do your stuff;
}
```

**EDITED:**

In your Case you need to add such like,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TouchViewMethod:)];
gestureRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
gestureRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[ annotationView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRec];
```

Comment: it does not catches the touches though

Comment: @erdemgc - check my edited answer, here call only simple method `(TouchViewMethod:)` on touch just for testing :)

Comment: now the problem is centerOffset method of annotationView, my custom annotation's image is located at the below and right of the point

Comment: @erdemgc - pleas put image with your problem :)

Comment: i should not put image but its size is 65*49, also i could not do it; when i touch this annotation, the method is not called, it is only when the left-top point of a image is touched working